# Apply sobel filter in live time camera android

Tags: android, filter, camera, google-cardboard, sobel

I am developing a camera application in android, that i want is to apply a sobel filter in live time. I read this is posible with OpenGL and OpenCV (I don`t know which is easier). Can anyone help me?

My app is for a cardboard, but this is irrelevant fot this question.

Comment: In my experience OpenCV has a quite steep learning curve, while OpenGL should be relatively simple to set up since it is provided by Android itself (e.g. there are official API guides from Google etc.)